# Is Developer Edition required for Sonarqube analysis on Pull Requests?

Tags: sonarqube, bitbucket, bamboo, pull-request

This could be a silly question, but I am spending a whole day and met this message saying:

> Was not able to fetch data for Sonar project "myapi-project:feature/test-sonarqube". Either your pull request has not been analyzed yet, a non-existing Sonar project is referenced, you use the new branching feature of SonarQube 6.7 but have not enabled this in the repository settings or you have upgraded SonarQube without restarting the plug-in (disabling and re-enabling in the UPM). You can configure the Sonar project in the repository settings.

I am currently using SonarQube 7.1 and configured correctly and restarted many times. I just wonder if the analysis is not conducted because I am using Community Edition, not Developer Edition, or above.

According to the Sonarqube website, Developer Edition is for those who want to analyze code on branch basis.

Is it the matter of upgrading edition?

Or

Did I miss something? If so, I think I should consider integrating Pull Request Notifier for Bitbucket as mentioned in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49563056).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to their documentation:

> Pull Request analysis is available as part of Developer Edition and higher.

You can find additional details here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Pull+Request+Analysis

Also, you may need to upgrade to SonarQube 7.2+ to use the pull request analysis feature as mentioned here: https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SCAN/Analyzing+with+SonarQube+Extension+for+VSTS-TFS